# SQL Server Primary File Group full when tables set to use Secondary

Tags: sql-server, database, filegroup

I have a database with two file groups, the second file group (Default) being used for the database tables.

For some reason, when I check the file group sizes, the Primary file group is still being used to store all the data while the secondary appears to be as its initial size.

I have double checked that the tables are on the secondary file group by viewing the table properties Filegroup field.

Why is this database still using the primary file group ?

---

Additional information. 
I ran @Vishal Gajjar's referenced script which identified that one table (the largest table) is not entirely using the secondary Filegroup as its still using the Primary for the "Text Filegroup".

[image]

Comment: Use this [query](http://blog.extreme-advice.com/2013/01/17/list-of-table-in-filegroup-with-table-size-in-sql-server/) and see what tables/indexes stored in each file group.

Comment: Default `FILEGROUP` applies only when you create a table or index without specifying `ON [FileGroupName]` clause

Comment: I guess another approach is to add another database file to PRIMARY FILEGROUP. So new rows of old tables (pages in fact) will be added to new file (on another disk). But I can't tell you how DB server will balance use of those files. Of course when you have two filegroups you have more control (less important tables to slower disks).

Answer (score 0):

The default options specified on a database are only applied to the objects created after the option is changed. Existing objects will keep the options they had when they were created.

So:

- either modify the default options before creating any object
- or modify the objects one by one (or run an script to do so) if you didn't do the first option

As you've mentioned, you can keep the "limited size" columns in a file group and the "blob columns" (those with MAX length, text, ntext...) on a different file group (the Text filegroup)